# C# Canvas won't increase int variable

Tags: c#

I've tried to increase an `int` variable on drawing process within `Canvas`.

The variable `length` defines the next position for `DrawText`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Klass.KCode {
    class TextPanelLight : Canvas {
        private string content = null;
        private List<KCodeElement> elements = new List<KCodeElement>();

        public TextPanelLight(string content) {
            base.BeginInit();
            Console.WriteLine("New TextPanelLight");

            this.content        = content;
            KCodeParser parser  = new KCodeParser();
            this.elements       = parser.Parse(this.content);

        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext graphics) {
            base.OnRender(graphics);

            SolidColorBrush foreground  = Brushes.Black;
            int font_size               = 14;
            string font_name            = "Arial";
            double length               = 0;

            foreach(KCodeElement entry in this.elements) {
                FormattedText element = new FormattedText(entry.GetText(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(font_name), font_size, foreground, VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip);

                foreach(int[] bold in entry.GetBolds()) {
                    element.SetFontWeight(FontWeights.Bold, bold[0], bold[1] - bold[0]);
                }

                graphics.DrawText(element, new Point(length, 0));

                // THIS WONT WORK:
                length = length + element.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;

                Console.WriteLine(">>> " + ((int) element.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace));
                Console.WriteLine("+++ " + length);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

But the variable will not be updated, here the Output:

```
>>> 201 (this will be added)
+++ 201 (current value)
>>> 230 (this will be added)
+++ 230 (current value)
>>> 230 (this will be added)
+++ 230 (current value)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

I've had already cleaned up my project or manually delete the `bin` and `obj` directory of the `Visual Studio` project.

Comment: Each time, `+=` wont work. The same with `length = length + x`. I misunderstand, why the context is lost - Especially because i had defined the variable **within** the draw-method, before the loop starts.

Comment: Please change your code to include console writes immediately before and after the loop. The simplest explanation is that `this.elements.Count` is 1.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how `TextPanelLight` is being used.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Were you able to check the value of `this.elements.Count`?

Answer (score 1):

Spending a little time learning how to use the debugger may be time well spent, it would allow you to step through your code and see what's going on with your variables at each line code.

But without using a debugger you can still figure out what's going on.  First, you should convince yourself that adding something to length works. Adding the `Console.WriteLine` marked `//1` will show you that indeed `length` is zero before this line.

So, if length is zero at this point, what must be going on is that `OnRender` is not being called as you expect it to be called. You can figure this part out by adding the statements marked `//2` and `//3` which log when you enter and leave your `OnRender` method.

You haven't shown enough code for anyone to be sure, but it looks like each time `OnRender` is called, `this.elements` contains only one element. If this is true the problem is in code you have not shown us, but at least you'll know to look elsewhere.

Now, you'll have to remove all the `Console.WriteLine` statements, so that's another reason to learn how to use a debugger.

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext graphics) {
        Console.WriteLine("ENTER: OnRender with this.elements.length = " + 
            this.elements.length); // 2
        base.OnRender(graphics);
        SolidColorBrush foreground  = Brushes.Black;
        int font_size               = 14;
        string font_name            = "Arial";
        double length               = 0;

        foreach(KCodeElement entry in this.elements) {
            FormattedText element = new FormattedText(entry.GetText(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(font_name), font_size, foreground, VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip);

            foreach(int[] bold in entry.GetBolds()) {
                element.SetFontWeight(FontWeights.Bold, bold[0], bold[1] - bold[0]);
            }

            graphics.DrawText(element, new Point(length, 0));

            Console.WriteLine(">>> Before length = " + length); // 1
            length = length + element.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;

            Console.WriteLine(">>> " + ((int) element.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace));
            Console.WriteLine("+++ " + length);
        }    
        Console.WriteLine("LEAVE: OnRender"); // 3        
    }
```